# HttpContext.Current.Cache without expiration

Tags: c#, performance, caching

How do you think is it a good practice to cache objects without expiration like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
    key,
    value,
    null,
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

When I get entity from database, I put it to the Cache and if object changed I deleted cache item. And I don't need expiration, I think it will be good for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never want the items to expire you can use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead and put it in a `static` variable. It would also work for scenarios when the `HttpContext` is not available.
But you can never count on an item being in the Cache (or ConcurrentDictionary) since IIS recycles the application pool when it feels like it.

Comment: `ObjectCache` could also be used when access to the `System.Web` namespace is unavailable. This is for versions from .NET4 and newer.